# Python Flask REST authentication on Google Apps Engine

Tags: python, rest, google-app-engine, authentication, flask

I have a Python Flask implementation of some REST services I want to run on Google App Engine (GAE). I have the services running, but now I want to add some basic authentication to help add a security layer to my services and data. I have tried following Miguel's excellent article at: http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/restful-authentication-with-flask

But I get stuck on code sections like:

```
from flask.ext.httpauth import HTTPBasicAuth
auth = HTTPBasicAuth()

@app.route('/api/resource')
@auth.login_required
def get_resource():
    return jsonify({ 'data': 'Hello, %s!' % g.user.username })
```

From what I can tell, GAE does **not** support the use of `httpauth` and `HTTPBasicAuth`. Is that correct? Or is there a way to use these libraries on there? What would be the equivalent of something like this for GAE? I'm not looking to add a fancy layer of authentication like OpenID and stuff like that - and I don't want to require all my users to have a Google account. I'm really just looking for the most straightforward authentication allowed by GAE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can include additional pure-python third-party packages, you can
>   do so by setting up vendoring. Vendoring allows you to install
>   packages to a subdirectory of your project and include them in your
>   code. - [*Vendoring Third-party Packages*](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27)

1. `cd <your_appengine_project_directory>`
2. Create or modify `appengine_config.py` in the root of your project to contain the following:

   ```
   from google.appengine.ext import vendor

   vendor.add('lib')
   pip install -r requirements.txt -t lib/
   ```

   or for the last command:

   ```
   pip install Flask-HTTPAuth -t lib/
   ```

See https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-python-flask-skeleton for a flask skeleton on getting started with GAE